# Jsf: column header not displayed if included

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, facet

In a dataTable a column contains lots of images which are conditionally rendered one at a time. That content was common with other dataTables so I decided to move it in a separate file and now I have something like this:

```
<h:column><ui:include src="myFile,xhtml" /></h:column>
```

Inside the h:column tag there was also the following f:facet tag, which was moved with the rest of the code

```
<f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
```

Now the column content is correctly displayed but the header is empty. Why ?
Maybe the ui:include is evaluated after the column headers are created...in that case I would need to be pointed to a good documentation for gaining a better insight on how JSF builds and renders a dataTable.

I forgot to mention I'm using Mojarra 2.0/2.1.

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: Are you sure that file name is `myFile,xhtml` (with comma), not `myFile.xhtml` (with dot)?

Comment: Actually the file name is completely different, I wrote it as an example, and sure I did a typing error putting a comma where a dot is needed

Comment: @Filippo can't be done that way look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11023471/617373

Comment: I'm still missing something to fully understand it. myFile.xhtml contains both f:facet tag handler and other ui components. The last ones work fine but the header is not displayed. I can achieve my goal moving back the f:facet portion from myFile.xhtml and leave there only the ui components, but I would like to understand better what happens...